# ORA-01481: invalid number format model in oracle insert query

Tags: sql, oracle, date, insert, ora-01481

I have below query where i am getting error as

```
ORA-01481: invalid number format model
The user is attempting to either convert a number to a string via TO_CHAR or a string
to a number via TO_NUMBER and has supplied an invalid number format model parameter.
```

I am using this query in stored procedure. The day_id column is number data type and the value stored in this column as `YYYYMMDD`. The month_id column is also number data type and i want to stored the value in this column as `YYYYMM`

```
INSERT INTO TEST_CHECK(MONTH_ID) VALUES
 (to_char(REC.day_id, 'YYYYMM'));
```

Comment: `to_char()` returns a `VARCHAR` not a number so you can't store that into a `number` column

Comment: If all you want to do is lose the last two digits, isn't that `trunc(day_id/100)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're applying a conversion to a number as if it was a date, trying to use the result (a string) as a number.

```
SQL> create table TEST_CHECK(MONTH_ID number);

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO TEST_CHECK(MONTH_ID) VALUES(to_char(20180101, 'YYYYMM'));
INSERT INTO TEST_CHECK(MONTH_ID) VALUES(to_char(20180101, 'YYYYMM'))
                                                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01481: invalid number format model
```

You may need something like:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO TEST_CHECK(MONTH_ID) VALUES(substr(to_char(20180101), 1, 6));

1 row created.
```

I would remember that storing dates and months in such a way is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
INSERT INTO TEST_CHECK(MONTH_ID) VALUES
 (substr(REC.day_id, 1, 6));
```

instead, since both `day_id` and `month_id` are numbers.

If day_id were in `date` format you could make such a conversion to char but this not the case.

You may apply to_char conversion for `REC.day_id` as `to_char(REC.day_id)` but if there's `no non-numeric character`, oracle considers `number` as `char` implicitly without to_char, during a string operation such as `substr`.